# Mac Excel 2016 formula to add selected cells just by clicking on them

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2016

In a previous version of Excel, I could just click on each cell that I wanted to add and it would automatically put a `+` between each one. I can't figure out how to do that on this version.

So if I wanted to add `B24`, `B26`, `B28`, `B29` and `B30`, I would just click on each cell and it would automatically add those cells. How can I do that without manually putting a `+` between each one after I click the cell? Currently if I click on each cell it just replaces with the next cell I click.

Comment: In what function are you putting those cells? Maybe you mean Control+Click each cell?

Comment: Or maybe it's Command+Click on Mac

Comment: Yes...to add cells on Mac Excel... it's =SUM(Command click on each cell) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select non-adjacent cells in Excel for Mac, click the first cell that you want to add to the range and then hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> (Command) key and click each additional cell you want to add to the range.